# Missing package System.Numerics.Complex in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio, osx-elcapitan

I want to run a project from here https://github.com/se-passau/SPLConqueror/tree/master/SPLConqueror

I opened it in Xamarin Studio (I’m running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6), but in the file FeatureSubsetSelection.cs line 1287 (System.Array ret = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), A.S.ToIntArray().Reverse().ToArray()); ) it gives me the error

Error CS0012: The type `System.Numerics.Complex' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly`System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' (CS0012)

where A.S.ToIntArray().Reverse().ToArray() is said to be the critical part.

I added the nuget package System.Numerics.Vectors (because there was no other package with System.Numerics), but the error is still there.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add the reference System.Numerics ? Complex is defined there

Comment: How can I add a reference? I only know how to add a package.. Project -> Add NuGet-package->...

Comment: under the solution, references, right click add

Comment: Found it. Awesome, thank you!

Comment: You can mark BugFinder's answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add System.Numerics as a reference before you can use it.